# Why Circular Slider is not accessible on any UIimageView and Uiview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I am Using Circular slider in three classes. where i have three different Slider images and i want to add Circular Slider view (which is inherit from UIVIEW) on uiimageview.
This is my code:::

```
CircularSliderView *sliderView = [[CircularSliderView alloc] initWithMinValue:0 maxValue:100 initialValue:0];  
sliderView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
sliderView.frame=CGRectMake(88,160, 140, 150);
[self.view addSubview:sliderView];
```

It is not Working. if i adding it on Main view. it is working Properly.

I really don't know how it is going like this,please help me out!

Comment: please add "Not working code"

Comment: How you are adding Circular Slider in uiimageview add code of this line

Comment: here i  am using three below functions which is handing the sliderr moovement
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{}
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{}
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{}

in this touches ended function is not calling. when i move the dot of slider..

Comment: @Jignesh

CircularSliderView *sliderView = [[CircularSliderView alloc] 
[self.imageview addSubview:sliderView];

Comment: Try my answer, i hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

if you are adding sliderView in self.imageview

```
 [self.imageview addSubview:sliderView];
```

then write

```
self.imageview.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

By default UIImageview user interaction is disable

i hope this will work